# Git thinks I am someone else

Tags: git, github

Suddenly git thinks I am someone else.  The person it thinks I am is someone I work with, but I cannot find any reference as to why git thinks this.  I have check system level, local, and global level git configs, I have checked my ssh keys, not sure what else to check.  Maybe I should uninstall git?  Error is below.

```
remote: Permission to myusername/mitty.git denied to personiworkwith.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/myusername/mitty.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Comment: Have you checked what ssh keys is your current terminal using?  `ssh-add -l`. If you do not find your ssh-key listed there, probably that's a catch.

Comment: What client are you using? For https requiring authentication, you use a username/password combo. You need to verify they are set properly. How to do that really depends on what client you use, though.

Comment: There is no need to re-install Git. Since you are using `https://` rather than `ssh://` as your URL scheme, your ssh setup is irrelevant as well. What matters are, as @DanLowe said, your https credentials. These are OS and Git-version specific, so you need to mention both your OS and your specific Git variant.

Comment: What Git credential helper are you using?

Answer (score 5):

> unable to access 'https

That means it has nothing to do with ssh and ssh keys: it is an https url.

See what git remote -v returns, but if it is https, and if you have a credential helper (see git config -l | grep credential), that would explain why the wrong set of credential is used.

Try at least to force the right username with

```
cd /patH/to/my/repo
git remote set-url origin https://<myusername>@github.com/myusername/mitty.git
```

Or, of course, try and use ssh if you want:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:myusername/mitty.git
```

Comment: ya good call using ssh.  Still cannot find where or why my coworkers github creds were being sent up.  It was odd because it would say he pushed to a new branch, but my name was on the commit.  Super strange.

Answer (score 1):

If you're having this issue, you're probably on Windows using a Credential Manager like me. If so:

Credential Manager has your old co-worker cached, here's how to remove them.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/search?query=credential%20manager

For Windows 10: 
**Control Panel > Credentials Manager**, 
select Windows Credentials, 
**look for github.com ( ex: git:https://github.com )**, 
click the arrow to options/details, 
**Remove**

Now the next time you try to access remote ( ex: pushing to a new repo:)

```
git push -u origin master
```

etc... it will ask for your git creds. And should save them for next time.